# CSS selector for nested ul li comments

Tags: css, wordpress, nested, comments, selector

So, I've got my Wordpress comment template like this:

```
<ul class="children">
    <li class="comment bypostauthor">
        <span class="name">MYNAME</span>
        My comment
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="comment">
                <span class="name">ANOTHER USER NAME</span>
                user nested comment
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="comment bypostauthor">
                        <span class="name">MYNAME</span>
                        My nested answer
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
<style>
.comment .name {color:red;}
.bypostauthor .name {color:blue;}
</style>
```

I'de like to style .bypostauthor .name with a diferent color of the other comments, but since I'm using nested comments, every .name inside the first .bypostauthor turns blue.

I'm trying to come up with a CSS selector, but having no luck :(

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a23jX/

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
.comment .name {color:red;}
.bypostauthor > .name {color:blue;}
</style>
```

The `>` selects only direct children.

Answer (score 1):

Use the child selector `>`

```
<style>
    .comment > .name {color:red;}
    .bypostauthor > .name {color:blue;}
</style>
```

---

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/a23jX/1/

---

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

> A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element.
>   A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".